# Azure WCF Service in a Web App rather than a Classic Cloud Service

Tags: azure, wcf

I have created a Xamarin Android App that uses Azure for the back end.  It seems that it would be better to host it in an App Service, but in Visual Studio 2017 Community, the only option seems to be to host it in a Classic Could Service.  In VS, I created a Cloud Service project and added the WCF Project as a Role.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can publish your WCF project directly to azure App service.

Comment: When I try that, it asks me which Cloud Service I want to publish it to.  Can you point me to some instructions that will work with VS 2017.  Most of the stuff I have found is for earlier versions of VS and the illustrations don't look the same as what I see.

Comment: Deploy your project using FTP

Comment: @CSharpRocks This is my first time time using Azure.  Can you point me to a link that describes how to do this or maybe just list some steps that I can try to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use Visual Studio Web Deploy, you can use FTP to deploy your compiled project.  The FTP information is located in the Overview blade of the App Service.  In the same blade, you can also click on the Publish Profile button to download an XML file containing credentials for Web Deploy and FTP.

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_8YQwsnE1s) explaining the whole process.